# Save chosen option in drop down menu after reload

Tags: html

I'm using this drop down menu:

HTML:

```
<ul id="dropdown">
    <li> Choose theme
    <ul> 
        <li id="stylesheet1" > <a href="#"> Default </a></li>
        <li id="stylesheet2" > <a href="#"> Theme 1 </a></li>
        <li id="stylesheet3" > <a href="#"> Theme 2 </a></li>
        <li id="stylesheet4" > <a href="#"> Theme 3 </a></li>

    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
#dropdown {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }
#dropdown li {
 background: #F7F0E0;
 border:1px solid #666;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding:0 0 0 10px;
 position: relative;
 height:20px;
 width:100px;
}
#dropdown li:hover {
 background: #FF2828;
}
#dropdown li a {
 text-decoration:none;
}
#dropdown ul {
 background: #F7F0E0;
 display: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 20px;
 left: -1px;
 z-index: 500;
}
 #dropdown ul {
 position: absolute;
   }
 #dropdown li:hover ul {
 display: block;
 }
```

Is it possible that the option chosen is kept for the next time the page reloads? Or should I make another drop down, for example:

```
<form>
<select id="myList" >
  <option id="stylesheet1">Default</option>
  <option id="stylesheet2">Theme 1</option>
  <option id="stylesheet3">Theme 2</option>  
  <option>Theme 3</option>
</select>

<form>
```

I am using javascript and cookies on my page, should I use this to be able to this as well?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies, while it may work, are not safe. Some of your users may have disabled cookies so it won't work for them.

To keep the option chosen the next time the page reloads you are better with a server-side script that put some persistance in your data. You may read about [PHP POST & GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) and [PHP Session](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php).

As an alternative you may add the option chosen in the [localStorage](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5/local-storage.html) (html5). However, this alternative won't work with old browsers.

Comment: I can't really handle PHP so I will stick with cookies for now. I've been looking on an onChange event handler but I can't get it to work with the `<form> <select>` version.

Comment: You should probably use a polyfill (http://www.jstorage.info/) instead of cookies.

Comment: @Bart I prefer not use things like that.